# hibernate many to many и ошибка java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, java-ee, jpa

Есть унаследованная база данных, пытаюсь построить вокруг нее приложение. 
Проблема в том что я получаю периодически Duplicate entry при попытке вставить данные в связанные таблицы.

К примеру есть сущность Video и есть сущность Actor. 
В каждом видео снимается множество актеров, и каждый актер снялся в нескольких фильмах, поэтому связь Many to many.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "videos")
public class Video implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private int year;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "film_actors",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "film_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "actor_id")
    )
    private Set<Actor> actors = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Video video = (Video) o;

        return title != null ? title.equals(video.title) : video.title == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return title != null ? title.hashCode() : 0;
    }

    //getters setters
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "actors")
public class Actor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "actors")
    private Set<Video> video = new HashSet<>();

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Actor actor = (Actor) o;

        return name != null ? name.equals(actor.name) : actor.name == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

Проблема в том что когда я в своем сервисе пытаюсь сохранить новую сущность Video с актером который уже есть в таблице actors (с таким же именем), я получаю ошибку что он не может быть вставлен, и это рационально так как на таблице стоит ограничение уникальности на столбец Actor.name.

Какого поведения я жду? Я надеюсь что hibernate поймет что в таблицу Actors уже есть уникальное значение не будет в нее пытаться вставить снова актера с таким же именем возьмет его id и положит в связанную таблицу film_actor.

Это возможно сделать ?

сейчас я делаю что то вроде этого, что бы обойти мою проблему, это кажется не правильным решением. 
Это единственный путь ?

```java
 @Override
    public void save(Video video) throws SQLException {

        Set<Actor> actors = video.getActors();
        Set<Actor> mapped = new HashSet<>();
        for (Actor actor : actors) {
            Actor fromDb = actorRepository.findByName(actor.getName());
            if (fromDb != null) {
                mapped.add(fromDb);
            } else {
                mapped.add(actor);
            }
        }
        video.setActors(mapped);

        videoRepository.save(video);
    }
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}` у `Set<Actor> actors` в классе `Video`.

Comment: @Tsyklop, спасибо за ответ. Я вспомнил почему я поставил ALL. Сейчас убрал и получил 
`
rg.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: ru.common.model.Actor; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: ru.common.model.Actor
`

Comment: Убирание/установка `CascadeType.ALL` не решает проблему

Answer (score 0):

Проблема с дубликатами в вашем случае возникает из за неправильного понимания работы Hybernate.

Вы сравниваете объекты по `title` или `name` что не верно. Для сравнения `Entyty` должен использован ключ. Есть масса [статей](https://thorben-janssen.com/ultimate-guide-to-implementing-equals-and-hashcode-with-hibernate/), которые объясняют почему и для чего это делается.

Методы `equals` и `hashCode` для `@Entity Actor` должны выглядеть следующим образом:

```java
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Actor actor = (Actor) o;

        return Objects.equals(id, actor.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }
```

Comment: Хорошо. Вы видите код. Как изменить `class Actor` чтобы все работало, согласно вашей информации?

Comment: @ilw добавил пример в ответ.